# How to delete Xcode source control that remains after removing .git on the command line?

Tags: xcode, git

Here you can see there is no .git file because i removed it

```
rm -rf .git
```

[image: Source Directory]

And here you can see that Xcode still has a reference to the git repository.

[image: Xcode Repository Tab]

I'd like to recover the history.

Downloading a new version from github doesn't work because it's missing a project.pbxproj file online.

=0

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to delete the .DS_Store folder in the directory of the .git file.